# systemd user and group in environmentfile

Tags: unix, redhat, environment, systemd

I have a service that looks something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=someApplication
...
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/environment.file
Type=simple
User=$APPLICATION_USER
Group=$APPLICATION_GROUP
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "$APPLICATION_HOME/app.sh $APPLICATION_OPTS"
PIDFile=$APPLICATION_HOME/application.pid
...
```

in my environment.file I have

```
APPLICATION_USER=test_user
APPLICATION_GROUP=test_group
APPLICATION_HOME=/opt/application
APPLICATION_OPTS= -d test
```

If I try starting this I get the message "Unit application.service entered failed state." if I move the properties for User and Group into the service it works.

Working example:

```
[Unit]
Description=someApplication
...
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/environment.file
Type=simple
User=test_user
Group=test_group
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "$APPLICATION_HOME/app.sh $APPLICATION_OPTS"
PIDFile=$APPLICATION_HOME/application.pid
```

Is there a way to move the User and Group into an environment file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systemd does not support environment substition for *User* and *Group* Options. See [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Options)

You have to provide a literal *string* or *id*

Comment: I figured, but had to be sure :) Thanks for the help!